# Stop UIView animation, without advancing to the end

Tags: ios, uiview

Is there anyway to stop a UIView animation, but not jump to the end values?
I'd like to continue from where I am, instead of having a jerky looking 'snap' before it starts moving to it's new position

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer for other people who stumble here. Quite simple really, just pass 'options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState' into the options, and it will resume from it's current locaiton

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                 animations:^{
                     self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(visibleFrame.origin.x, visibleFrame.origin.y);
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){}
 ];
```